# How to create a validation with conditionals if a number is not multiple of 10.000 trigger error advice?

Tags: python

I make an algorithm for a cash box retire money ATM, I need that if ask retire a value and if it is not multiple of 10.000 trigger an advice:

```
Type a valid, value {value} is not accepted. In the case that the typed value is not multiple of 10k
```

My solution is create a Function where the retirement value is divided by 10.000. And if the result of the division gives a float result trigger the error advice.

```
def multiple10k_validation(inserted_value):
validation_result = inserted value/10000
if alidation_result ==
retunr f Type a valid, value {value} is not accepted. In the case that the typed value is not 
multiple of 10k

print(multiple10k(1550000))
```

Some people advise me that create a module apart to validate the value of the bills. But dont know how to do it.
Thanks

Comment: `if value % 10000 == 0` is a good validation test

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code is not valid python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is good, but you shouldn't use division. Instead use the modulo operator `%`. It returns the remainder of a division e.g. `9 % 4 = 2 remainder 1`. See also this [guide about the operator](https://realpython.com/python-modulo-operator/) it may help to understand it.

So in your code you would check for remainder 0, when applying modulo 10000:

```
def multiple10k_validation(inserted_value):
    if inserted_value % 10000 != 0:
        return "Type a valid, value {value} is not accepted. In the case that the typed value is not multiple of 10k"
    
    return "Valid value"

print(multiple10k_validation(1550000))
```